# Cannot Build SCons

Tags: scons

I'm trying to bootstrap-build SCons default branch of the official Bitbucket repo using existing scons version 2.5.1

through

```
python bootstrap.py
```

but it errors as

```
EnvironmentError: No module named gxx:
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/SConstruct", line 59:
    SConsignFile()
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 604:
    env = self.factory()
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 584:
    default_env = SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment()
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Defaults.py", line 88:
    _default_env = SCons.Environment.Environment(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Environment.py", line 982:
    apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Environment.py", line 107:
    env.Tool(tool)
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Environment.py", line 1789:
    tool(self)
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 225:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Tool/default.py", line 40:
    for t in SCons.Tool.tool_list(env['PLATFORM'], env):
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 1134:
    cxx_compiler = FindTool(cxx_compilers, env) or cxx_compilers[0]
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 1021:
    t = Tool(tool)
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 107:
    module = self._tool_module()
  File "/home/per/ware/scons/bootstrap/src/engine/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 190:
    raise SCons.Errors.EnvironmentError(e)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you install the required packages, as described in https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/SconsBuildRequirements ?

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: Also with that command line, you're not using any installed scons, just the checked out tree.  Please send an email to scons dev mailing list.